# How is Horizontal Visibility and RVR related and how does it affect the Low Visibility Operations?

Tags: visibility, extreme-weather

So on my foggy landing  the METAR 9 minutes before the touchdown stated Horizontal Visibility as 0000 and RVR 100

whereas the metar 21 minutes after my landing stated Horizontal Visibility 0100 and RVR 750

Now when I landed the visibility was very poor even the runway borderline were blurred by fog for the much part of rolldowm however,I could see around 46 to 50 something meters as per my own research on Google earth based on the markings and taxiway signs I could see presumably from the centreline.

So I wanna know why is the visibility 0000 when I could still see 46ish meters though vaguely but I could see it ?

Also,Does dos horizontal visibility effect the Low visibility procedures ? I mean if RVR is above CAT I conditions however the rest of airport has 100 meter visibility then would it still be Low Visibility procedures or just normal operations ?

Thanks

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between RVR and visibility?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/73979/what-is-the-difference-between-rvr-and-visibility)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between RVR and visibility?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/73979/what-is-the-difference-between-rvr-and-visibility)

Comment: Yes to an extent but I'm still wondering does Visibility affect Low Visibility procedures or not.